# Surface Pro 3 Print Screen

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-surface-pro

Windows 8.1:

From the "Surface Pro 3 User Guide":

> To take a snapshot of your screen, press and hold the Windows  button on your Surface, and then press the volume-down button. The screen dims briefly when the screen is captured.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Yes;  It worked for me

Comment: I would like to add you can also use the pen to take a screen capture because of OneNote.

Answer (score 4):

Using my type cover, <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> works for me. Starting with <kbd>Fn</kbd> instead of the Windows key prevents the start screen from appearing.

Answer (score 2):

I found that I could not do this using the Windows key on my type cover, but then I re-read and tried it simultaneously using the Windows icon on the surface body itself. It worked on the first try.

Comment: I found that you can press and hold the windows button on the Surface and then press the volume down button. The press and hold makes it much easier.

Answer (score 2):

**With keyboard (copy to memory):**

FN + Space (full screen, previously PrtScn)

Alt + FN + Space (active window, previously Alt + PrtScn)

**Without (Saves as file in Pictures Library > Screenshots):**

Windows Button + Vol Down

Answer (score 1):

For me the screenshot works with **Win-Fn-Spacebar**.

I don't see a Volume Down button on my keyboard.

Comment: There wouldn't be one.  This is the hardware shortcut that the user wants to use.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why most answers here tell about keyboard shortcuts. The question is about hardware buttons on the Windows-based tablet, not about keyboard shortcuts. It's important to note that this should work on any Windows(8)-based tablet. E.g. Microsoft Surface, Dell Venue Pro, you name it.

In order to take a screenshot, press (and hold) Windows button on the device and then Volume Down hardware button.

[image]

Comment: i don't have an external keyboard (so no FN key). this illustration was worth a thousand words for a no keyboard screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I have done it a few times, but it's a simultaneous action. Pressing the Windows button first takes you to the tiles, and pressing the volume down button first lowers the volume. Both must be touched/pushed at the same time to work.

Answer (score 0):

Both buttons are to be pressed together, and it works if your timing is right.

The screenshot will be saved in *My Documents* → *Pictures* → *Screenshots*.

Answer (score 0):

Click each of the following in sequence, keeping your fingers on each:

- ***First*** click the *function* key (so you don't change screens to the start up screen),
- Next the Windows key
- Third the space bar.

The screen will darken for half a second, indicating that the copy has taken place. Open your favorite picture software and paste it.